# Pandas: calculate time difference between different milestones in column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot

I have a  table like this:

| id | tm | milestone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00335c06f96a21e4089c49a5da | 2023-02-01 18:13:42.307543 | A |
| 00335c06f96a21e4089c49a5da | 2023-02-01 18:14:42.307543 | A |
| 00335c06f96a21e4089c49a5da | 2023-02-01 18:15:42.307543 | A |
| 00335c06f96a21e4089c49a5da | 2023-02-01 18:19:10.307543 | B |
| 00335c06f96a21e4089c49a5da | 2023-02-01 18:21:05.307543 | C |
| 0043545f6b9112c7e471d5cc81 | 2023-02-02 08:06:42.307543 | A |
| 0043545f6b9112c7e471d5cc81 | 2023-02-02 08:07:42.307543 | A |
| 0043545f6b9112c7e471d5cc81 | 2023-02-02 09:05:42.307543 | B |
| 0043545f6b9112c7e471d5cc81 | 2023-02-02 09:05:42.307543 | B |
| ffe92ae6b0962e800dbdbdf00a | 2023-02-12 19:05:42.307543 | A |
| ffe92ae6b0962e800dbdbdf00a | 2023-02-12 19:05:42.307543 | B |
| ffe92ae6b0962e800dbdbdf00a | 2023-02-12 19:07:42.307543 | B |
| ffe92ae6b0962e800dbdbdf00a | 2023-02-13 21:03:42.307543 | C |

What I want to achieve - is convert it to transactional view / pivot so that for each `id` to have columns with max time difference between milestones (A, B, C, D..). For starting - columns `A-B`, `A-C`.
Treaky part that there are multiple records with same milestone - I am taking min time for each category.  But also not all id have full sequence, in this case I need to mark this time difference as None.

For Example:

| id | A-B, min | A-C, min |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00335c06f96a21e4089c49a5da | 5.47 | 7.38 |
| 0043545f6b9112c7e471d5cc81 | 59.0 | None |
| ffe92ae6b0962e800dbdbdf00a | 0 | 1558.0 |

What I'm trying to do:
Take min values for each milestone:
df.groupby(['id','milestone '])['tm'].min().to_frame('tm').reset_index(),

And apply `.diff()` like `.sort_values(['id','tm']).groupby('id')['tm'].diff()` But can't feagure out how to properly do this to create time-difference columns.
Other idea is to use `.pivot` but can't come up with idea how to aggregate milestones inside.

Appreciate any help.

Input DataFrame for example:

```
pd.DataFrame({'id':['00335c06f96a21e4089c49a5da','00335c06f96a21e4089c49a5da','00335c06f96a21e4089c49a5da','00335c06f96a21e4089c49a5da','00335c06f96a21e4089c49a5da','0043545f6b9112c7e471d5cc81','0043545f6b9112c7e471d5cc81','0043545f6b9112c7e471d5cc81','0043545f6b9112c7e471d5cc81','ffe92ae6b0962e800dbdbdf00a','ffe92ae6b0962e800dbdbdf00a','ffe92ae6b0962e800dbdbdf00a','ffe92ae6b0962e800dbdbdf00a'],
             'tm':['2023-02-01 18:13:42.307543','2023-02-01 18:14:42.307543','2023-02-01 18:15:42.307543','2023-02-01 18:19:10.307543','2023-02-01 18:21:05.307543',
                  '2023-02-02 08:06:42.307543','2023-02-02 08:07:42.307543','2023-02-02 09:05:42.307543','2023-02-02 09:05:42.307543',
                  '2023-02-12 19:05:42.307543','2023-02-12 19:05:42.307543','2023-02-12 19:07:42.307543','2023-02-13 21:03:42.307543'],
              'milestone':['A','A','A','B','C','A','A','B','B','A','B','B','C']})
```

Comment: how big is your real data?

Comment: It would really help if the data you displayed and the data you give the input constructor matched.   Along, with a valid expected output from this matching dagta.

Comment: @Ben.T, about 500 000 records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

> I am taking min time for each category

Just change the aggregation function of `pivot_table`:

```
df['tm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tm'])  # maybe unnecessary

m = df['milestone'] == 'A'  # first milestone or not

out = (pd.merge(df[m], df[~m], on='id')
         .assign(milestone=lambda x: x.pop('milestone_x') + '-' + x.pop('milestone_y'),
                 tm=lambda x: x.pop('tm_y').sub(x.pop('tm_x')).dt.total_seconds() / 60)
         .pivot_table(index='id', columns='milestone', values='tm', aggfunc='first')
         .round(2).rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                           id    A-B      A-C
0  00335c06f96a21e4089c49a5da   5.47     7.38
1  0043545f6b9112c7e471d5cc81  59.00      NaN
2  ffe92ae6b0962e800dbdbdf00a   0.00  1558.00
```

---

IIUC, you want to compare time between the first milestone (A) and other ones, so you can use `merge` before reshaping your dataframe with `pivot_table`:

```
df['tm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tm'])  # maybe unnecessary

m = df['milestone'] == 'A'  # first milestone or not

out = (pd.merge(df[m], df[~m], on='id')
         .assign(milestone=lambda x: x.pop('milestone_x') + '-' + x.pop('milestone_y'),
                 tm=lambda x: x.pop('tm_y').sub(x.pop('tm_x')).dt.total_seconds() // 60)
         .pivot_table(index='id', columns='milestone', values='tm', aggfunc=min)
         .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                           id   A-B     A-C
0  00335c06f96a21e4089c49a5da   3.0     5.0
1  0043545f6b9112c7e471d5cc81  58.0     NaN
2  ffe92ae6b0962e800dbdbdf00a   0.0  1558.0
```

Comment: Something wrong for id `00335c06f96a21e4089c49a5da` - time difference between `2023-02-01 18:13:42.307543` and `2023-02-01 18:19:10.307543` not 3.0min.

Comment: Ok, I've added before your solution groupby and select min date and now seems ok:
`df = df.groupby(['id','milestone'])['tm'].min().to_frame('tm').reset_index()`

Comment: What do you mean by *I am taking min time for each category*. You want the first date of `A` in fact?

Comment: @Alex_Y. I updated my answer and fixed the bug. Can you check it please if it solved your problem now?

Comment: Yep, exactly - first date.  All good, thanks!